# Publish Post to Contact

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

How do you publish a post to a contact using the Salesforce REST API? I cannot find any useful resources to complete this task. I have the Contact ID. I noticed a call sobjects/Note however its not working as I thought.

Comment: Did you want to publish a chatter post?

Comment: I am not sure, I just want to be able to post a note and link it to a contact. Is that something that can be done via a Chatter post?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was able to post to a contact using the [chatter/feed-elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resource_feeds_news.htm) POST endpoint with the following PHP array encoded to json prior to sending:

```
$salesforce_note = [
        "body" => [
            "messageSegments" => [
                [  
                    "type" => "Text",
                    "text" => $note
                ]
            ],
        ],
        "feedElementType" => "FeedItem",
        "subjectId" =>    $contact_id
    ];
```